# Kubernetes service without a external IP, not able to access the service

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I'm trying to deploy my container in a kubernetes cluster but I'm not getting an External ip and hence I'm not able to access the server.

This is my .yaml file:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    kompose.cmd: kompose convert
    kompose.version: 1.21.0 (992df58d8)
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: service-app
  name: service-app
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      io.kompose.service: service-app
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        kompose.cmd: kompose convert
        kompose.version: 1.21.0 (992df58d8)
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        io.kompose.service: service-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: magneto-challengue:1.0
        imagePullPolicy: ""
        name: magneto-challengue
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
        resources: {}
      restartPolicy: Always
      serviceAccountName: ""
      volumes: null
status: {}
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    kompose.cmd: kompose convert
    kompose.version: 1.21.0 (992df58d8)
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: service-app
  name: service-app
spec:
  ports:
  - name: http
    protocol: TCP
    port: 8080
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    io.kompose.service: service-app
    type: NodePort
```

When I use the `kubectl get svc,deployment,pods` command. I'm getting the next response:

[image]

As you can see I'm not getting an external Ip. With the `kubectl describe service service-app` command I'm getting the next response:

[image]

I tried with the `10.107.179.10` ip, but it didn't work.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You can not use `10.107.179.10` IP to access a pod from outside kubernetes cluster because that IP is clusterIP and is valid inside the kubernetes cluster and can be used from another pod for example.

`NodePort` type does not get an `EXTERNAL-IP`. To access a pod from outside the kubernetes cluster via NodePort service you can use `NodeIP:NodePort` where `NodeIP` is any of your kubernetes cluster nodes IP address.

Comment: Is it an on-prem or cloud set?